# Reading Custom Property from Blender Game Engine

Tags: game-engine, properties

I'm using the BGE to read a custom property that I set in Blender on the default Cube object. For some reason, the property doesn't show up in the BGE? Am I missing something obvious? All the documentation I can find says I can just access it with `obj['propertyName']`, but it doesn't work.

```
cube = bge.logic.getCurrentScene().objects["Cube"]
print(cube['min'])  # KeyError: 'value = gameOb[key]: KX_GameObject, key "min" does not exist'
print(cube.get('min'))  # Returns None
print(cube.getPropertyNames())  # Empty list
print(cube.attrDict)  # Empty dictionary
```

Version is Blender 2.78; to run the engine, I just do `blenderplayer myfile.blend`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom properties belong to Blender. They are not converted and do not exist in the BGE.

You need to set up game properties (game logic editor).

Comment: Oh, so that's what I was missing. Custom Properties != Game Properties.
But why does `cube.get('min')` work, and `cube['min']` does not?

Comment: Both work. The difference is that dict.get(key, fallbackValue) returns the fallback value (defaults to None) when there is no entry with the provided key while dict[key] will result in an KeyError.

Answer (score 0):

In the script that is run by the Blender 2.79 BGE include:

```
import bpy
```

yeah, I know it's against the rules.
Then use this line to access the object's custom properties

```
variable = bpy.data.objects['ObjectName']['custom property']
```

Comment: The reason it's "against the rules" is because this will only work in blender. The stand alone player does not have the bpy module, so your code will not work.